# Go. Working with huge csv files

Tags: csv, go

We have big dataset - couple of tens of csv files, that ~130Gb each. 
We must emulate sql query on csv table.

When we're reading test table using `encoding/csv` on test 1.1 Gb file - program allocates 526 Gb of virtual memory. Why? `csv.Reader` works like generator, when we using `reader.Read()` method, or it keeps row in memory?

Full [code](https://gist.github.com/tigrus/e5d9bed4cde33773284d2c7dc4468beb) after [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/124444/summing-chemical-properties-in-a-csv-stream).

**UPD**

Reading file like:

```
rf, err := os.Open(input_file)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error: %s", err)
}
r := csv.NewReader(rf)
for {
    record, err := r.Read()
}
```

Falling on line `record, err := r.Read()` with memory error.

**UPD2**
Snapshot of memory during read process:

```
 2731.44MB 94.63% 94.63%  2731.44MB 94.63%  encoding/csv.(*Reader).parseRecord
     151MB  5.23% 99.86%  2885.96MB   100%  main.main
         0     0% 99.86%  2731.44MB 94.63%  encoding/csv.(*Reader).Read
         0     0% 99.86%  2886.49MB   100%  runtime.goexit
         0     0% 99.86%  2886.49MB   100%  runtime.main
```

Comment: SO is not a code review site.  Update your question with the relative code snippets as well as sample input data.

Comment: @eduncan911, attached related code to question.

Comment: inspect ur data for line break and CR characters codes and post some sample data of where those characters are.

Comment: @eduncan911, I think, it should fail on first row if there are no line-break. It fails with memory leak on row number 4123819381 or so.

Comment: maybe that record 4123819381 and on is missing line breaks?  the only times i've seen this kind of trouble when reading files is when slicing slices or arrays and adding to maps.  basically, if you don't copy the slice and use the new slice as-is, it will hold onto the old slice as you keep building in the collection - thinking GC will remove the old slice (it wont).  Basically, I'm saying that unless it is a `linebreak` issue, **the csv reader is not your issue.** look elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @eduncan911, why it's reading line by line, if there are no line break? It really logically fails on line, where memory can be over. We have 16Gb RAM, temporary file size - 5Gb at the moment of fail.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the line breaks aren't being detected and its reading everything as a single record.

https://golang.org/src/encoding/csv/reader.go?s=4071:4123#L124

If you follow the code to line 210, you'll see it look for `'\n'`.

Often times I see line breaks defined as `\n\r` when some system exported it, thinking they were being Windows-smart when in fact it's wrong.  The correct Windows linebreak is `\r\n`.

Alternatively, you can write a custom `Scanner` that will deliminate the lines for you using whatever technique you have in your input, and use it as the `io.Reader` input for your `csv.Reader`.  For example, to use the invalid `\n\r` I mentioned above.